# Code First Migration: Two foreign keys referencing on the same table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following Models in ASP.NET(Core 1.0) MVC Framework. I am using Entity Framework Core. I want to create a table "Deliveries" with two foreign keys from the same table Addresses(a pick-up address and a drop-off address). My implementation is wrong so I would like to ask you if you know:

1. how to declare those properties
2. how to set onupdate and ondelete actions for those keys?

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using JBCoreApp.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace JBCoreApp.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VehicleType> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LicenseCategory> LicenseCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DriverLicense> DriverLicenses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sender> Senders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DeliveryStatus> DeliveryStatus { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Delivery>()
                .HasOne(a => a.DropOffAddress)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


            builder.Entity<Delivery>()
                .HasOne(a => a.PickUpAddress)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Address>(a=> a.Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


        }
    } 
}
```

**Address.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace JBCoreApp.Models
{
    [Table("Addresses")]
    public class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ProfileId { get; set; }
        public Profile Profile { get; set; }

        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
        public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public string CountryId { get; set; }
        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Delivery.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JBCoreApp.Models
{
    [Table("Deliveries")]
    public class Delivery
    {
        public Delivery()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SenderId { get; set; }
        public Sender Sender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
        public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PriorityId { get; set; }
        public Priority Priority { get; set; }

        public int DriverId { get; set; }
        public Driver Driver { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PickUpAddressId")]
        public Address PickUpAddress { get; set; }
        public int PickUpAddressId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DropOffAddressId")]
        public Address DropOffAddress { get; set; }
        public int DropOffAddressId { get; set; }

        public DateTime PickUpDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime DropOffDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public Byte[] TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: currently, you have to set the navigation properies from both sides (one-to-one), Address.Delivery and Address.DeliverySecond : here is an example: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#one-to-one